# Solve the following system of simultaneous congruences:

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

\begin{gather}
3x\equiv1 \pmod 7 \tag 1\\
2x\equiv10 \pmod {16} \tag 2\\
5x\equiv1 \pmod {18} \tag 3
\end{gather}

Hi everyone, just a little bit stuck on this one. I think I am close, but I must be getting tripped up somewhere. Here is what I have so far:

from (2), $2x=10+16k \implies x=5+8k$

Putting this into (1):

\begin{align*}
3(5+8k) \equiv 1 \pmod 7
&= 15+24k \equiv 1 \pmod 7 \\
&= 24k \equiv -14 \pmod 7
\end{align*}

By co-prime cancellation, I get $12k\equiv -7 \pmod 7$

And since $12k \equiv 5k \pmod 7 \implies 5k \equiv -2k \pmod 7$ and $-7 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$, we conclude that
$ -2k \equiv 0 \pmod 7 \implies -2k = 7l$ for some integer $l$.

Multiplying by $-4 \implies 8k = -28l$

It follows that,  $x = 5 + 8k = 5-28l \implies x \equiv 5 (mod \space -28) $

So now, solving (1), (2) and (3) is equivalent to solving:

$x \equiv 5 (mod \space -28) $ (4)

$5x\equiv1 (mod\space 18)$ (3)

Then substitute $x = 5-28l$ into (3),

$5(5-28l) \equiv 1 (mod \space 18)$

= $25 - 140l \equiv 1 (mod \space 18)$

= $140l \equiv 24 (mod \space 18) $

And since $140l \equiv 14l (mod \space 18) \implies 14l \equiv -4l (mod \space 18)$ and $24 \equiv 6 (mod \space 18)$

we have, $-4l \equiv 6 (mod \space 18) \implies -4l = 6 + 18M$ for some integer M.

Multiplying by 7 $\implies -28l = 42 + 126M$

Finally, substituting this back into x, $x = 5-28l \implies x = 5+42+126M = 47+126M \implies x \equiv 47 (mod \space 126)$

But when I substitute $x = 47$ back into my original equations, it works for (1) and (3), but fails for (2).

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, but a guide to a simplification. The first congruence is fine. Note that the second congruence is equivalent to $x\equiv 5\pmod{8}$. Any solution of this congruence must be odd.

Now look at the third congruence. Note that as long as we know that $x$ is odd, we automatically have $5x\equiv 1\pmod{2}$. So in the presence of the second congruence, the third one can be replaced by $5x\equiv 1\pmod{9}$.

Thus we are looking at the congruences $3x\equiv 1 \pmod{7}$, $x\equiv 5\pmod{8}$, and $5x\equiv 1\pmod{9}$. Now the moduli are pairwise relatively prime. Relatively prime moduli are easier to handle, there is less risk of error.

There will be a unique solution modulo $(7)(8)(9)$. In particular, your final modulus of $126$ cannot be right.

It is probably worthwhile to simplify the congruences still further. Note that the congruence $3x\equiv 1\pmod{7}$ has the solution $x\equiv 5\pmod{7}$. And the congruence $5x\equiv 1\pmod{9}$ is equivalent to $x\equiv 2\pmod{9}$.

We got lucky, ended up with $x\equiv 5\pmod{7}$ and $x\equiv 5\pmod{8}$, which has as only solution $x\equiv 5\pmod{56}$.

So we are trying to solve $x\equiv 5\pmod{56}$, $x\equiv 2\pmod{9}$.

One can find a solution by a short search.   Or else we want $x=56a+5=9b+2$. That gives $9b=56a+3$, so $3$ must divide $a$, say $a=3c$. We arrive at $56c+1=3b$. Clearly $c=1$ works, so $a=168$. The solution is therefore $x\equiv 173\pmod{(56)(9)}$.

Comment: Hi Andre, thanks for your guidance. I just don't really understand your 2nd paragraph. Could you elaborate a little bit on this - I understand that from (2), we get that x must be odd. but how does that lead to 5x≡1(mod2)? And then how do we just replace (3) with 5x≡1(mod 9)? If you could step me through this part, I think I will understand. Thanks!

Comment: The congruence $5x\equiv 1\pmod{18}$ is equivalent to the two congruences $5x\equiv 1\pmod{9}$, $5x\equiv 1\pmod{2}$. The second of these just says $x\equiv 1\pmod{2}$, it just says $x$ is odd. If the second congruence $x\equiv 5\pmod{8}$ holds, then automatically $x\equiv 1\pmod{2}$, so we don't need to ask that $x$ is odd. So the system of congruences $x\equiv 5\pmod{8}$, $5x\equiv 1\pmod{18}$ has the same solutions as $x\equiv 5\pmod{8}$, $5x\equiv 1\pmod{9}$.

Comment: Thanks very much Andre, that makes sense. Just to confirm my understanding of equivalences in mod arithmetic - We have that 5x≡1(mod2) gives x≡1(mod2), because 5x≡x(mod2) right? So is it correct that in modular arithmetic we can in a sense simplify one side, without having to change the other side? Thanks so much.

Comment: That's right, in modular arithmetic we can add, subtract the modulus as many times as we wish without changing anything. (With n umbers in the **exponent**, like $x^{74}\equiv 3\pmod{11}$, the situation is different. Dealing with that will come later.)  So for example $5x\equiv 99\pmod{7}$ is the same as $5x\equiv 1\pmod{7}$, since $99=98+1$ and $98$ is divisible by $7$. Sometimes it is useful to make numbers "bigger". To solve $2x\equiv 1\pmod{7}$, note it is equivalent to $2x\equiv 8\pmod{7}$, and then to $x\equiv 4\pmod{7}$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be where you write "So now, solving (1), (2) and (3) is equivalent to solving..."

This isn't true. $$x \equiv 5 \;(\bmod 28)$$ is not enough - one of the implications is correct, but equivalence only holds with $$x \equiv 5 \;(\bmod 56 = 8 \cdot 7).$$ The reason for this is essentially the Chinese remainder theorem.

There is a similar problem later on. The solution of this system is actually determined modulo $lcm(7,8,18) = 504$.